# Software Recommendation Low level, relatively verbose audio libraries

Tags: command-line, sound, software-recommendation

I recently changed window managers to dwm, and one of the things that I've really enjoyed about it is having to figure out a lot more about how exactly ubuntu handles things like wireless connections. I'm looking for something similar for music. I'm looking for something that is a command line utility that will put me very close to the metal of how playing music actually works.

I've seen a lot of recommendations for command line based audio players, but I'm looking for something that a lot of people seem to not be looking for. I'm looking for something along the lines of write a shell script to make a playlist.

Any good packages like this?

Answer (score 0):

There are few audio applications which do not make use of more basic audio application inherent to all Linux distributions including Ubuntu. Per default Ubuntu audio is based on ALSA with most of it's libraries and low level tools already installed:

- [ALSA project](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Main_Page)

However we can also install another sound sond subsystem like e.g. the

- [Open Sound System (OSS)](http://www.opensound.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

On top of these we need a sound server to make further use of the basic sound system, e.g.:

- [PulseAudio](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio) (default) - For desktop sound applications
- [Jack - Audio Connection System](http://jackaudio.org/) (optional) - For professional sound systems
- [Music Player Demon MPD](http://www.musicpd.org/) (optional) - for networking applications

Many sound applications make use of the [gstreamer](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) multimedia framework, wich can also be addressed directly, or in own applications.

After we had a look at the different solutions we can see that the Ubuntu sound system can nicely be controlled and accessed via command line utilities, even for finer acpects of sound control. The amount of graphical load depends on the music player you are using, but it can all be done without any player at all.

This is especially true for playlist, which are simple text files that can be made with any editor. Below is a basic example of an .m3u playlist file:

```
#EXTM3U
/path/to/music_library/file1.mp3
/path/to/music_library/file2.mp3
...
```